# gorm .where with like

Tags: grails, grails-orm

New to groovy, grails.

I have the following query where I want to match a few paramater exactly to as passed(eq), but for one, which I want to using a 'like'

```
if (params.ret_code) {
            ret_cod = params.ret_code+"%"
 }       

    def srchresults = DmnObj.where {
    if (params.doc_num) { doc_num == params.doc_num.trim() } //works as expected

    //How do I do this????
     if (params.retn_code) { retn_code like ret_cod }

    }
```

Tried this, but in-vain.

how do I set retn_code with a like?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do this

```
    // case sensitive like 
    def result = Domain.where {
        fieldName ==~ "value"            
    }

    // case insensitive like 
    def result = Domain.where {
        fieldName =~ "value"            
    }
```

Remember to prefix, suffix or both the `value` with `%`. For more about `where` queries https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#whereQueries

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
var feel []DB.Feelings
db.Where("column_name LIKE ?", "%"+yourText+"%").Limit(your_limit).Offset(your_offset).Find(&feel)
```

**column_name** is your column name

**Limit** and **Offset** are not required

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
def result = DomainClass.where{
    like('fieldName', '%'+myVariable+'%')
}
```

I suggest you have a look at the Grails documentation (section [Domain Class Usage](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/Usage.html)): you will find several interesting ways to filter your domain class objects as for example `HQL` queries or `findAllBy*` dynamic methods.

Comment: Edit your question and add the exact code you are trying so we can see what's not working