# golang-gorm .where with like

Tags: go, go-gorm

i couldn't find any thing like this but it is exactly like (not in golang ) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481655/gorm-where-with-like)

DB.Where(like(client))

should i make a function that return the sql query

edit : i meant using a struct not a string query

Comment: Struct？ You mean Map ?

Comment: no i meant using a struct like in the documentation but with the "like" condition gorm docs ; db.Where(&User{Name: "jinzhu"}, "name", "Age").Find(&users)

Comment: I think it can't implement in `gorm`. I didn't find that way to do this in the `gorm` documentation.

Answer (score 5):

From the GORM docs e.g.

```
db.Where("name LIKE ?", "%jin%")
```

https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Conditions

Comment: Sorry ididnt clarify but i meant using a struct instead od a string

Answer (score 0):

i wrote a function that returns a SQL query :

```
func like(s interface{}) string{
    val := reflect.ValueOf(s)
    var name string = val.Type().Field(0).Tag.Get("json")
    var value interface{}
    var res string
    for i := 0; i < val.NumField();i++{
        name = val.Type().Field(i).Tag.Get("form")
        value = val.Field(i).Interface()
        if name != "-" && name != "" && value != ""{
            if res != ""{
                res += fmt.Sprintf("AND %s LIKE \"%%%v%%\" ",name,value)
            } else {
                res += fmt.Sprintf("%s LIKE \"%%%v%%\" ",name,value)
            }
        }
    }
    return res
}
```

sorry for the messy code

edit : the problem with the function is that it is vulnerable against
SQL injections i use bindQuery() and the injection worked plz give me a solution
gorm doc : https://gorm.io/docs/sql_builder.html#Named-Argument